# Transcluded element not being deleted on removal of list item when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a widget that I'm instantiating using `ng-repeat`. Initial creation works fine, but after that it stops updating. Here's an excerpt from `index.html`:

```
<div>
  <x-node ng-repeat="node in nodes"></x-node>
</div>
```

partials/node.html:

```
<div>{{node.name}}</div>
```

And the directive:

```
angular.module('directive', []).directive('node', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'partials/node.html',
        replace: true,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
                        console.log('destroying');
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

If I modify the list of nodes in the console like this:

```
var e = angular.element($0);
var s = e.scope();
s.nodes.splice(1,1);
s.$apply()
```

... then the `$destroy` callback runs, but the rendered elements do not change. Is there something I'm missing from my directive?

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U8UGQl6JMRGjz9DZcvtz?p=preview)

Comment: Shouldn't `template` be `templateUrl`?

Comment: @JosephSilber ah yes, and indeed it is. Thanks, I fixed that in the question.

Comment: @Arun, Thanks for the Plunker demo! I notice that if the template is included in the directive without using a templateUrl, it seems to work...

Comment: This may be a bug.  You may want to follow https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/0CP0zpTnZMM/5OzBni7d9sgJ.

Comment: @toshshimayama I see - there's also this bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151 It looks like templateUrl has some issues at the moment. For now I'll just use template. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was indeed a bug, which is fixed in the 1.2 series of AngularJS. [Here's an updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QMsVKpYaJApmyJQq2C6F?p=preview) that uses 1.2.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="my-app">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppController">

    <div id="ct">
      <x-node ng-repeat="node in nodes"></x-node>
    </div>

    <button id="test">Remove element [1]</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.nodes = [{
          name: 'one'
        }, {
          name: 'two'
        }, {
          name: 'three'
        }];


})

app.directive('node', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'node.html',
        replace: true,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
                        console.log('destroying');
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});

$(function(){
  $('#test').click(function(){
    var el = $('#ct').children().first();
    if(el.length){
      var e = angular.element(el[0]);
      var s = e.scope();
      s.nodes.splice(1,1);
      s.$apply()
    }
  })  
});
```

node.html:

```
<div>{{node.name}}</div>
```