# ng-repeat not binding when directive template is loaded via templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been stuck on this for hours and hours - can anyone help?

I have a list of nested directives, which I'm iterating through ng-repeat.  The templates for these directives are fairly chunky so I've modularised them into separate HTML files and loaded them via templateUrl, but this seems to be breaking the data binding.

I've replicated the problem here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/72HUb0vhtpYWuRHnlq3b?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div project-ext ng-repeat="project in projects"></div>
```

project.html

```
{{project.name}} <button ng-click="projects.splice($index,1)">-</button><br>
<div schedule-ext ng-repeat="schedule in project.schedules"></div>
```

schedule.html

```
{{schedule.name}}<button ng-click="remove($index)">-</button>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('projectExt', function() {
    return { 
        templateUrl: 'project.html'
    };
});

app.directive('scheduleExt', function() {
    return { 
        templateUrl: 'schedule.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.remove = function(i) {
                scope.$parent.project.schedules.splice(i,1)
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Can anyone tell me why the remove buttons don't work in the second listing, when all I've done is change the directives construction from template to templateUrl?

Comment: You should include relevant code examples in your post to make the question self-contained.

Comment: Sorry, really hard to summarise the problem without seeing the plunker ...

Comment: It's totally fine to have a plunk, but you should always include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems to be related to a bug reported at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

To workaround it, simply don't put `ngRepeat` and your directives which are using `templateUrl` on the same element; instead, place `ngRepeat` on an wrapper:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects"><div project-ext></div></div>
```

project.html

```
{{project.name}} <button ng-click="projects.splice($index,1)">-</button><br>
<div ng-repeat="schedule in project.schedules"><div schedule-ext></div></div>
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/BapWX0LpqkcLFegq1fhU

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks very much for clearing that up.  Hopefully the bug gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug, please follow these links. You can use the other version you wrote as a workaround.

[Transcluded element not being deleted on removal of list item when using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160549/transcluded-element-not-being-deleted-on-removal-of-list-item-when-using-ng-repe)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/0CP0zpTnZMM/5OzBni7d9sgJ