# Different scope when using ng-repeat and custom directive in one element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive like:

```angular
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/views/myView.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope); 
            console.log(angular.element(element).scope());
        }
    };
});
```

the template html is:

```angular
<div>{{item.text}}</div>
```

and view html is:

```angular
<div ng-init="items=[{text:'hello'}, {text: 'world'}]">
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in items"></my-directive>
</div>
```

I find the `scope` and `angular.element(element).scope()` is not the same one, but I have to use `angular.element(element).scope()` way to get the scope of ngRepeat-item somewhere else.
Am I misunderstanding something?

***Note***:

The code could be reproduced only when including jQuery.

Comment: You are right. Also faced the similar problem..

Comment: As a side note...you don't need to wrap your element on angular.element - it's already  an angular element.

Comment: @Darren You are right

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates child scopes for each item

Comment: Tested with AngularJS 1.2.19 and for each item `scope` and `angular.element(element).scope()` **do return the same object**. But different items have their own `scope`. What version are you using?

Comment: @AllenZeng I'm using 1.2.17. Do you use `template` instead of `templateUrl` in directive? `template` works like what i expect.

Comment: @xtang `templateUrl`. I copied everything you have here over to plunker

Comment: It seems to be like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236267/ng-repeat-not-binding-when-directive-template-is-loaded-via-templateurl

Comment: @AllenZeng Yes, I cannot reproduce it in plunker. But it's really happened in my laptop. Another reference https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

Comment: @xtang can't reproduce it on my local workstation either, even with 1.2.17 :/

Comment: @AllenZeng Sorry. I'm missing something that I used the jquery2.1.1 on my local. After removing the jquery, ng-repeat works as expected. But I indeed needs the jquery

Comment: @AllenZeng, here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTsigT3p2B68aYKZG3yX?p=preview

Comment: @xtang it's probably a good idea to raise an issue for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is related [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9122).

The main reason is: angular1.2.x does not support jQuery2.0.x, and angular1.3.x will do.

So the solution here will be:

- angular1.2.x + jQuery 1.x
- angular1.3.x + jQuery 2.x
- angularjs only